# How do I cycle through different classes whenever I click a div in jquery?

Tags: jquery

I have this div with class whose possible values "class01" to "class10".

I want to cycle through the different classes whenever the div is clicked.

Is there something similar to toggleClass(class) but accepts multiple classes as input?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could make a mini-plugin that does it:

```
$.toggleClassOnClick = function(prefix, max){
   return this.addClass(prefix + 1).data('cur', 1).click(function(){
      var $this = $(this), 
           curr = $this.data('cur'),
           idx  = cur + 1;

      $this.removeClass( prefix + curr);

      if(idx > max) idx = 1;
      $this.addClass( prefix + idx).data('cur', idx);
   });
}
```

You would use it like this:

```
$("#mydiv").toggleClassOnClick('class', 10);
```

And it will assign `class1` to the div, and on every click increment the class until it reaches `class10`, then start back at `class1` again. If you wanted to use `class01` you can adjust this code as necessary.

Comment: That should probably be `$.fn.toggleClassOnClick = ...`, not `$.toggleClassOnClick = ...`.

Answer (score 0):

maybe: http://jqueryui.com/demos/accordion/

cycling is for?? (you use toggle, hide and show them, correct?)

Answer (score 0):

How about something like this?

```
var num =0;
function pickAClass()
{      
  // lots of different ways to do this bit
  switch(num++)
  {
    case 1:
      return "class01";
    ...          
  }
}
```

then when you toggle...

```
toggleClass(pickAClass());
```